# Using $scope within angular.element function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm setting an attribute on my directive and I can access the value from within the controller but I can't access it within my angular.element which is in the controller:

```
controller: ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
      console.log('my value is logged: ' + $scope.myvalue)
    angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
      console.log('my value is not logged: ' + $scope.myvalue)
    }
}],
```

I want to append elements to the dom only if `$scope.myvalue` is true and when a scroll point has been reached on the page.

How would I do this?

Comment: The scroll event callback is outside of the angular digest cycle, have you tried wrapping the call to `console.log` using `$scope.$apply`?

Comment: already modules around that have all this worked out for you

Comment: Have you tried angular.element($window).on() instead of .bind()?

Comment: Got it sorted.  `$scope.$apply` worked:  `$scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.header;
            $scope.footer;
         });`

Comment: @mzulch if you want to answer the question I'll accept your `$scope.$apply` answer:)